# How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?

Tags: math-mode

I have a very long equation that must be separated into two lines, and it has several pairs of nesting `\left` `\right` delimiters. Unfortunately, it seems that they need to be on the same line in order for them to work.

Also I'm using the `align` environment because I need the aligning functionality. Is there a way to have the size of delimiters automatically adjusted over multiple lines?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The [`breqn` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) is a package that defines a set of new math environments, with the purpose of enabling automatic line breaking of displayed math. These new environments also let you have `\left` and `\right` on different lines, though it is not the main goal of the package.

Note that the package has several known problems and incompatibilities, so depending on your use case it might not be for you. I recommend a look at the manual.

---

The example below is one where you definitely shouldn't use `\left` and `\right` in the first place, but it serves to illustrate that it works. The `dmath` environment is similar to `equation`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper, margin=5cm}

\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
Automatic breaking:
\begin{dmath}
55 - \left(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10\right) = 0
\end{dmath}

Manually breaking a line seems to work as well:
\begin{dmath}
55 - \left(1+2+3+4+\\5+6+7+8+9+10\right) = 0
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it compatible with `amsmath` and `amssym`?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler Judging from the manual, yes, but load `breqn` _after_ any other packages dealing with math, such as those you mentioned.

Comment: Warning that breqn package caused errors in my existing align equations; seemed to be related to the underset command. Using virtual dot delimiters (\right.) was a much simpler solution in this case - the answer by Mark Mikofski

Comment: `breqn` and package for allowing big brackets over more than one line. 119 pages of packages documentation. Welcome to Latex.

Comment: @spinkus I won't argue that there can be a lot of documentation, but it's not really as bad as the page count indicates. The last 100 pages is about the implementation, i.e. it's code with explanation. So most users need only look at the first 20 pages.

Comment: Would be good to add an example to this.

Comment: `breqn` is incompatible with `unicode-math`. They promised to add Unicode math in 2009. It's 2020. So I would say `breqn` is dead.

Comment: This does not seem to be working. Loaded with `\usepackage{breqn}`. Breaking with `\\ ` in between `\left` and `\right` still gives the same errors for me.

Comment: It is such a shame that the only package that attempts to allow line breaks between `\left` and `\right` also attempts something far more ambitious, and in my opinion unnecessary, and as a result ends up incompatible with everything and therefore ends up being useless. I would have loved a package that only attempted to allow breaks between `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @Kvothe Well, the more ambitious goal was the original goal I suppose. As you probably realized, `breqn` doesn't enable that feature in, for example, the `amsmath` environments, just the environments defined by `breqn` itself. I should have expanded my answer years ago, sorry about that.

Answer (score 99):

You can't.

You can use some thing like `\biggl`, `\biggr`, or `\left.\vphantom{...}\right)`. For example:

```
\[
\begin{split}
a &= \left( \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 \right. \\
  &\quad \left. {}+ a + b + c \vphantom{\frac12}\right)
\end{split}
\]
```

Comment: Note that the alignment points (the `&`s) have to be outside the `\left`/`\right`.

Comment: Could one modify `\left` and `\right` to include `\vphantom`s of all the lines in between?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: It's not easy to determine what to put in the `\vphantom`. TeX cannot understand the meaning of the equations. Anyway, you can use `breqn`.

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to get this kind of pre-formatting from Mathematica for large system of equations? More [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77586/formatting-latex-dump-from-mathematica-equations-for-a4-paper-without-manual-a).

Comment: @hhh: `breqn` package should be useful. (See above)

Comment: I tried \biggl and it works perfect.

Comment: @LevBishop: what should one do if one needs an alignment tab inside `\left...\right`? Use `\right. & \left.`?

Comment: @Blaisorblade: Indeed. Sometimes we need `\right.` and `\left.`, and sometimes we even need `\vphantom`.

Comment: It's funny that even Word can automatically break equations over multiple lines and has no problems of breaking inside matching braces. After decades LaTeX still can't do it. I thought that the LaTeX's best part in contrast to Word is separation of content and presentation. “You can just concentrate on writing” is a usual motto of LaTeX aficionados when they try to explain the advantage of using LaTeX.

Comment: This is a better answer for more general situations.

Comment: Great answer, this helped me enormously, thanks so much!

Comment: `\vphantom` is the solution I was looking for all along! It always irked me when i used 
`\left( <...> \right. \\ \left. <...> \right)` and the brackets ended up with different sizes.

For anyone reading this: `\vphantom{}` hides whatever you put in, while still scaling braces to what ''should'' be there, so just put the ''tallest'' thing in your equation, and all lines will scale according to that. E.g.

`\left( <something short> \vphantom{\frac{1}{1}} \right. \\ \left. <something tall> \right)`

Answer (score 59):

The solution for me was to use *virtual dot delimiters*

```
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} &= \left[ \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \right. \\
                              &* \left. \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right]
```

which was the comment posted by [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52343/22116) which was marked as a duplicate.

The *virtual dot delimiters* are in [Leo Liu's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674/leo-liu) [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21291/22116) above, but a TeX n00b like me wouldn't have seen it.

FYI Sphinx-1.1.3 **already** [supports multi-line math with the math directive](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/math.html#directive-math) using the [AmSMath LaTeX package](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex), *i.e.* [breqn](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) is not necessary.

Comment: This doesn't give the right sizes if the material on the first and second lines have different height. Leo Liu's answer corrects for this by adding the `\vphantom`.

Comment: Thanks [eldering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4131/eldering), that's very good to know!

Comment: I could not see where sphinx makes a line break with `\left` in the link which you provided. How does sphinx solve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [`nath` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nath).

Comment: Is it compatible with `amsmath`?

Comment: @Tobias: No. As I know, it is uncommon to use `nath`.

Comment: @Tobias: `nath` is incompatible with `amsmath`; it does provide some support for multi-line display, and lot of nice features like automatic scaling of delimiters (no need for `\left` ... `\right`) that also works across line breaks, ignoring the height of the subscripts and superscripts (of operators like `\sum`) when calculating the scaling of delimiters, smart display of `\frac`, amongst others which do are cumbersome when using `amsmath`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I wanted to show this equation

```
\begin{equation*}
    V_{sal} = -\left(1.V_8 + \frac{1}{2}.V_7 + \frac{1}{8}.V_6 +\frac{1}{8}.V_5  + \frac{1}{16}.V_4 \right.\\
     \left. + \frac{1}{32}.V_3 + \frac{1}{64}.V_2 + \frac{1}{128}.V_1\right) 
\end{equation*}
```

but since it is too long (in a two column document), I used `multline` enviroment but it gives an error (something like `Missing \right. inserted. \end{multline*}` or `Extra \right. \end{multline*}`). I solved it with this new code

```
\begin{multline*}
V_{sal} = -\left(1.V_8 + \frac{1}{2}.V_7 + \frac{1}{8}.V_6 +\frac{1}{8}.V_5  + \frac{1}{16}.V_4 \right.\\
 \left. + \frac{1}{32}.V_3 + \frac{1}{64}.V_2 + \frac{1}{128}.V_1\right) 
\end{multline*}
```

Note that I added a `\right.` at the end of the first row and `\left.` at the beginning of the second row.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your answer is the same as of @Mark Mikofski (difference are only in used parenthesis/ bracked.

Answer (score 2):

The previous "automated" solutions all use certain packages that have compatibility issues with `amsmath`. Here is a sort-of-automated solution that does not require additional packages.

This solution uses `\vphantom` and is in essence the same as the previous answers using this command.

```
% split \left and \right across two lines
% use only between \[ and \] (modify as needed for \begin{equation}\end{equation}, etc.)
\newcommand\MatchBrackets[2]{\left[#1\vphantom{#2}\right.\]\[\left.\vphantom{#1}#2\right]}
\newcommand\MatchParentheses[2]{\left(#1\vphantom{#2}\right.\]\[\left.\vphantom{#1}#2\right)}
```

Usage:

```
\[\nabla h=\MatchParentheses{\int_0^{e^5}e^{-z^2}dz+\frac12\cdot\cos\left(\frac12\cdot x\right)\cdot\cos(y),}{-\frac12\cdot\cos\left(\cos\left(\frac12\cdot y\right)\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac12\cdot y\right)-\sin(x)\cdot\sin(y)}\]
```

(Idea taken from [Wintz's comment here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49890/linebreak-between-left-and-right#comment1472435_49895). Example modified from [zdim's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36669489).)

Comment: I welcome suggestions/feedback on the "user interface" for these commands—is "\MatchParentheses" a good name? should I make the command take 4 arguments, with two of the arguments specifying the delimiter symbols? "(), [], {}, ..." etc.