# Linebreak between \left and \right

Tags: math-mode, equations, delimiters

I would like to type something like this:

```
\begin{equation}

  \begin{split}

    \left( ba ba ba \\

    ba ba ba \right)

  \end{split}

\end{equation}
```

But it contains error; I think it's because `\left(` and `\right)` should be in the same line. How can I type something like this, but in different lines? I think one of the solution is replaced `\left(` and `\right)` by `\Big(` and `\Big)`. But I am not satisfied with it since `\Big(` is not "big" enough compared to `\left(`.

Comment: How about `\biggl( ... \biggr)` or `\Biggl( ... \Biggr)`?

Comment: ^ I seriously suggest everyone struggling with the same problem as OP to use `\big(` notation. Syntax: `( \big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg(`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

if you want the parentheses of the same height, use `\vphantom` and a combination of `\left( ... \right. \\ \left. ... \right)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \left( \int_1^2 ba ba \mathrm da \right. \\
    \left. ba ba ba \vphantom{\int_1^2} \right)% use height of \int
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\vphantom` command (short for "vertical phantom") tells LaTeX to makes an invisible box that is the height of its contents
https://latexref.xyz/_005cphantom-_0026-_005cvphantom-_0026-_005chphantom.html#:~:text=The%20%5Cvphantom%7Ba%5E3,of%20the%20use%20of%20%5Cvphantom%20.

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically, say, if we have \left\right inside a macro?

Comment: @PaulWintz I wrote a macro here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/686204 . The macro is for `\[...\]` environments, but it should be simple to modify to work for other environments, including `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \left( ba ba ba \right. \\
    \left. ba ba ba \right)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You were right about the fact that the `\left` and `\right` should be on the same line.

Comment: This will not give parentheses of the same size if the height of the contents on the two lines is different.