# latex typesetting multiline alignment with flalign

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, align, multline

I'm trying to align the second line equation below the integral in the first line. How do I go about doing that? I have used \right. commands to be able to move onto the next lines. I didn't have to use the \vphantom{} command to keep the parenthesis the same size as discussed in [vphantom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49890/linebreak-between-left-and-right)

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{xfrac}
 \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{flalign*}
 =-\frac{Is'n}{2\pi}\mathbf{\hat{z}}\left[\frac{1}{\frac{4xs'}{h}\frac{2\sqrt{xs'}}     {k}}\left(z-z'\right)  \left(\left(x'+s\right) \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\alpha}          {\left(1-h\sin^2\alpha\right)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\alpha}}\right.\right.  \\
 \qquad \left.\left.-2x\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2\alpha\:d\alpha}{\left(1-     h\sin^2\alpha\right)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\alpha}}\right)\right]_{z'=-\sfrac{L}     {2}}^{z'=+\sfrac{L}{2}}
 \end{flalign*}\\
 \end{document}
```

It doesn't allow to to use the & to align due to the parenthesis. Thanks

Comment: do you mean you want to align the integral signs?

Comment: Just to help anyone else - I just spent a few mins looking at this before seeing the comment below the code about & not working because of parentheses... doh!

Comment: if you select the size of the unmatched parentheses using, for example, `\bigr)` or `\Bigr)`, then there is no need for `\left.` and the `&` can be used.  but i'm sure this has been answered in other questions already.

Comment: I could have sworn I added a comment; @barbarabeeton is totally right, I've reinserted my answer and fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned a lot today, never had to play with parentheses of different sizes before. As @barbarabeeton says, you can use `alignat` if you explicitly specify the sizes of the unmatched parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{xfrac}
 \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
 \usepackage{mathtools}

 \begin{document}


Your equation:     
 \begin{flalign*}
 =-\frac{Is'n}{2\pi}\mathbf{\hat{z}}\left[\frac{1}{\frac{4xs'}{h}\frac{2\sqrt{xs'}}     {k}}\left(z-z'\right)  \left(\left(x'+s\right) \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\alpha}          {\left(1-h\sin^2\alpha\right)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\alpha}}\right.\right.  \\
 \qquad \left.\left.-2x\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2\alpha\:d\alpha}{\left(1-     h\sin^2\alpha\right)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\alpha}}\right)\right]_{z'=-\sfrac{L}     {2}}^{z'=+\sfrac{L}{2}}
 \end{flalign*}\\

Simple example to show what I added
\begin{alignat}{1}
 = a & b \notag \\
   & c
\end{alignat}

Your equation in alignat
\begin{alignat*}{1}
  = -\frac{Is'n}{2\pi}\mathbf{\hat{z}}\Biggl[\frac{1}{\frac{4xs'}{h}\frac{2\sqrt{xs'}}     {k}}\left(z-z'\right)  \Biggl(\left(x'+s\right) &  \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{d\alpha}{\left(1-h\sin^2\alpha\right)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\alpha}} \notag \\
      -2x & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin^2\alpha\:d\alpha}{\left(1-h\sin^2\alpha\right)\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\alpha}}\Biggr)\Biggr]_{z'=-\sfrac{L}     {2}}^{z'=+\sfrac{L}{2}}
    \end{alignat*}

 \end{document}
```

This is what the output of the above looks like

[image]

Comment: can you add an image of the output?  i think it would help others to visualize the situation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes will try to do that