# Size of { in my equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, delimiters

[image: Equation]

I write some code to get the above equation. However, I would like to make the first "{" to have the same size as the last "}". Does anyone know how to do it? I am attaching my code in the following

```
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Q}=\text{diag}&\left\{\text{diag}\left\{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \ \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \ \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}\right\}\right., \ \ldots\notag\\
&\quad \left.\underbrace{\ldots, \ \text{diag}\left\{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \ \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \ \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}\right\}}_{N_x}\right\}
\label{eq:Q}
\end{align}
```

Comment: See [Linebreak between `\left` and `\right`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49895/5764).

Comment: Do you really need to inform user that `m_1,\dots,m_K` makes `K` elements? IMHO it's a bit ridiculous. If you get rid of these inner `\underbrace`s, you'll be fine then, won't you?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I `\smash`ed the outer `\underbrace` of the 2nd line and added `\vphantom` of the same size as the inner `\underbrace`.  That way, the `\right\}` picks up on the `\vphantom` height.

Note that because the outer `\underbrace` was `\smash`ed, you will likely have to add a small `\vspace` after the equation to make up for the space taken up by the outer `\underbrace`, as shown in my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Q}=\text{diag}&\left\{\text{diag}\left\{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \ 
\mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \ \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}\right\}\right., \ \ldots\notag\\
&\quad \left.\smash{\underbrace{\ldots, \ \text{diag}
\left\{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \ \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \ 
\mathbf{m}_K}_{K}\right\}}_{N_x}}\vphantom{\underbrace{m_1}_{N_x}}\right\}
\label{eq:Q}
\end{align}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To follow up on a comment by the OP, if one wanted the braces on the inner diag arguments to be smaller, one *could* use the same technique I used on the outer diag.  However, in this case, I think I would use something like `\bigg\{ ... \bigg\}`, which I show in the first line of the MWE below, or else `\big\{ ... \big\}`, which I show in the second line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Q}=\text{diag}&\left\{\text{diag}\bigg\{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \ 
\mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \ \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}\bigg\}\right., \ \ldots\notag\\
%
&\quad \left.\smash{\underbrace{\ldots, \ \text{diag}
\big\{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \ \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \ 
\mathbf{m}_K}_{K}\big\}}_{N_x}}\vphantom{\underbrace{m_1}_{N_x}}\right\}
\label{eq:Q}
\end{align}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is pretty nice. In order to keep the consistency, do you know how to change the inner diag{} part in the same way as outside diag{}.

Comment: @user2270626  If I understand your question properly, I would not use `\left\{ ... \right\}` for the inner braces, but rather `\{\, ... \,\}`, which would use normal size braces for the inner diag arguments.

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean. If you can make the inner under brace and "K" lower than {} in the same way as the outer, that would be great for me. Thank you again.

Comment: @user2270626  See my more recent comment.  I can post an MWE, if it would help.

Comment: @user2270626, ...or, alternately, you could use `\big\{ ... \big\}`, or else `\bigg\{ ... \bigg\}`, or even `\Bigg\{ ... \Bigg\}`.

Comment: Steven, can you post an MWE for me to understand? Thank you for you help.

Comment: @user2270626 Please see addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A classic TeX method -- "classic" in the sense that it's mentioned explicitly in Knuth's TeXbook -- for achieving your objective is to repeat the material from the second line that's causing the closing curly brace to be so large inside a `\vphantom` macro on the first line. A `\vphantom` ("vertical phantom") is an invisible object that's as tall as its argument. In the code below, I've simplified your setup a bit by defining an auxiliary macro called `\bigblock` (sorry, not very creative) that's used twice -- first as the argument of `\vphantom` on the first line, then as itself on the second line. Additionally, I've defined another auxiliary macro named `\smallblock` that's an important building block (pun intended) of `\bigblock`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
%% define to auxiliary macros: \smallblock and \bigblock
\newcommand\smallblock{\diag\left\{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \
     \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \ \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}\right\}}
\newcommand\bigblock{ \underbrace{\ldots, \ \smallblock}_{N_x} }

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{Q}=\diag
&\left\{ \vphantom{\bigblock} \smallblock \right., \ \ldots \notag\\
&\quad \left.\bigblock \right\} \label{eq:Q}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need two lines for this formula, and  the `mathtools` package allows to define a `\diag` command that includes the variable sized braces. You then have a `\diag*` that adds an implicit `\left …\right` pair on either side of the braces. The non-star version admits as optional argument `\big`, `\Big`, &c. for fine tuning the size of the braces. Moreover, you get a code that has the sake of simplicity.

If you want to break your equation in two lines, there is a silghtly less simple code, adapted from a code in the `mathtools` documentation:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} %

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\Diag }[1]{\mathrm{diag}}\{\}{}{#1}

\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
\bgroup
\catcode‘\&=9
\let\\\relax%
\scantokens{#1}%
\egroup
}

\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set\{\}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\set{star}{
\mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
#2
\mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{Q}&= \Diag[\bigg]{\Diag{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}}, \ \ldots
\underbrace{\ldots, \ \Diag{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}}}_{N_x}}
\label{eq:Q}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{Q}= \diag&\set[\bigg]{\Diag{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}}, \ \ldots \\[-1ex]
 & \quad\underbrace{\ldots, \ \diag\set{\underbrace{\mathbf{m}_1, \mathbf{m}_2,\ \ldots, \mathbf{m}_K}_{K}}}_{N_x}}
\label{eq:Q}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have to break it into two lines because this equation is too long for me.

Comment: @user2270626: I also have a solution with line breaking. See my updated answer.