# how to write multiline equation with right brace alone

Tags: equations

**I am wrting this equation with**

```
\begin{eqnarray}
u_k^{n+1}=\argmin_{u_k \epsilon X} 
 \left\lbrace \alpha \left|\left|\partial_t\left[\left(\delta(t)+\frac{j}{\pi t}\right)*u_k(t)\right]e^{-j\omega_kt}\right|\right|_2^2
\\ +\left|\left| f(t)-\sum_i u_i(t) + \frac{\lambda(t)}{2} \right|\right|_2^2  \right\rbrace
\end{eqnarray}
```

but getting error

```
 ! Extra }, or forgotten \right.][1]
```

Comment: You cannot use the `\left ... \right` syntax across multiple lines of an `array`. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49890/linebreak-between-left-and-right, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73964/left-and-right-in-equation-across-multiple-lines

Comment: Search the site for `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big` and `\Bigg` as alternatives.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not balanced `\left` and `\right`s across line break. Further, better not use `eqnarray` but use `amsmath` facilities like `align` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}
u_k^{n+1}=\argmin_{u_k \epsilon X}
 \left\lbrace \alpha \left|\left|\partial_t\left[\left(\delta(t)+\frac{j}{\pi t}\right)*u_k(t)\right]e^{-j\omega_kt}\right|\right|_2^2 \right.\\ 
\left.+\left|\left| f(t)-\sum_i u_i(t) + \frac{\lambda(t)}{2} \right|\right|_2^2  \right\rbrace
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I have used `multlined` from `mathtools` (which also loads `amsmath`).

[image]

**Improved version:**

Instead of using `\left` and `\right` pair (which gives more space as noted by Mico and needs to be balanced across lines), you can use `Biggl` and `Biggr` from amsmath. Here is a screen shot from `amsldoc` page 15, (`texdoc amsldoc`):

[image]

And for double bar use a `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` like

```
 \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
```

and use it like `\norm[\bigg]{<content>}` (Thanks to Mico)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}
    u_k^{n+1}=\argmin_{u_k \epsilon X}
        \Biggl\lbrace \alpha \norm[\bigg]{\partial_t\left[\left(\delta(t)+\frac{j}
            {\pi t}\right)*u_k(t)\right]e^{-j\omega_kt}}_2^2 \\
        +\norm[\bigg]{f(t)-\sum_i u_i(t) + \frac{\lambda(t)}{2}}_2^2  \Biggr\rbrace
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One could,  as suggested by @MaxNoe, get automatic sizing of the double vertical bars by using the "starred" version of the command, viz., `\norm*{<content>}`. However, in the example at hand, doing so would generate delimiters that are *too large* -- hence the use of the explicit sizing directive, `\norm[\bigg]{<content>}`, in the code above.

Comment: The `\left|\left|` and  `\right|\right|` instructions leave too much whitespace between the vertical bars. Since the bars presumably denote a "norm", it would be better to write either `\left\lVert` and `\right\rVert` or, better still, set up a norm "operator" via `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}` in the preamble and then write `\norm[\bigg]{...}` in the equation.

Comment: \left|\left| schould be \left\Vert, possibly with a `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`

Comment: haha, same time

Comment: @Mico I was in a hurry to go home. Thanks, now answer updated.

Comment: you can use the starred version of `\norm` to get the size automatically, `\norm*{\frac{1}{2}}`

Comment: @MaxNoe Thanks, I added it. I am on and off now so many things are pending and work comes in discrete amounts :-)

Comment: @MaxNoe - Using `\norm*` will give you an *incorrect* size for the second norm expression. Automatic sizing is not foolproof... Better to use `\norm{\bigg]{...}`.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to mention it for completeness regarding `DeclarePairedDelimiter`

Comment: don't think anyone has mentioned it yet ... in the first example, the braces aren't the same size; the left brace is a tad smaller.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - You point out another good reason for *not* using `\left` and `\right` -- at least not without paying close attention to the fence sizes (in this case, the sizes of the curly braces).