# Problem with brackets in more than one row

Tags: arrays, brackets

I format my equations with an array to have them look nicer. I also use the `\left(` and `\right)` for brackets. One part of the equation is too long and needs to be splitted into two lines. This is my try so far

```
\begin{array}{ccl}
x & = & \left( … long term… \\
& & … long term … \right)
\end{array}
```

But this gives me the error `missing \right`. There is defenely no other missing `\right)` involved. If I remove the first `\left` and last `\right` it works, but I still want to keep my adjusted brackets. How to solve this?

Comment: take a look at [Linebreak between \left and \right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49890)

Comment: Note that `array` is designed to typeset arrays/matrices  your example of  `&=&` suggests you are using it for multiline equations, the spacing will be incorrect for that, far better to use `align` from the amsmath package.