# Multi-line brackets in align

Tags: amsmath, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines)

The following code (from the official [User's Guide for the amsmath Package](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)) works:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a& =b+c-d\\
& \quad +e-f\\
& =g+h\\
& =i
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

but this one doesn't:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a& =\left\{b+c-d+\\
& \quad +e-f\\
& +g+h\\
& +i\right\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

It complains with `Extra } or forgotten \right`. The second snippet tries to enclose the full equation in brackets. How can I do this with `\align`?

Comment: Amsmath doesn't bookkeep the delimiters over line breaks. You have to terminate with a virtual dot delimiter. `\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a& =\left\{b+c-d\right.\& \left.\quad +e-f\right\}\& =g+h\&  =i
\end{split}
\end{equation}`

Comment: Thanks @percusse. If you re-write that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: No problem, egreg found a duplicate so we can all vote for closing :)