# Splitting a long equation while maintaining size of brackets

Tags: math-mode, equations, brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines)

How can I have this equation:

```
\begin{eqnarray}\nonumber
\ln T &=& -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \left\{\ln(N2\pi\sigma_x(i)\sigma_y(i))\, \right.\\
    && \left. -\,\ln\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{M}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_j^2}{\sigma_x(i)}+\frac{y_j^2}{\sigma_y(i)}\right)\right] \right) \right\}
\end{eqnarray}
```

show the same size for the opening and closing brackets? Right now it looks like this:

[image: equation]

## Edit

This works:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  \ln T &= -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \Bigg\{\ln(N2\pi\sigma_x(i)\sigma_y(i))\, \\
  & -\,\ln\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{M}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_j^2}{\sigma_x(i)}+\frac{y_j^2}{\sigma_y(i)}\right)
 \right] \right) \Bigg\}
   \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
```

Comment: See [mathmode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)

Comment: See also: [align vs. eqnarray](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Comment: Brackets see: [“(” or “\left(” parentheses?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses)

Comment: see also [how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/)

Comment: This equation is also a good example of why *not* to rely blindly on the ability of `\left` and `\right` to generate correctly-sized parentheses, brackets, and braces. Instead, I would use `\Bigg\{` and `\Bigg\}` for the outermost braces and `\biggl` and `\biggr` pairs of parentheses and brackets on the second line.

Comment: It works using `amsmath` and @Mico's suggestion. Added to que question since it is now closed.

Comment: @Mico: Or simply use `nath`