# problem with \left| and align

Tags: align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines)

Hi I'm trying to write a long equation with `{align*}`:

```
\begin{align*}
&\left|<L(w^2u),Lu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k \right|= \\
&|<L(w^2u),Lu>_k-<wL(wu),Lu>_k+<wL(wu),Lu>_k\\
&-<L(wu),wLu>_k+<L(wu),wLu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k|\\
&\leq \left|<(Lw-wL)(wu),Lu>_k\right|+\left|<wL(wu),Lu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k\right|\\
&+\left|<L(wu),(wL-Lw)u>_k\right|
\end{align*}
```

and I find that when I try to add `\left|` and `\right` to the second and third line the code doesn't compile. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this and how to fix it:

```
\begin{align*}
&\left|<L(w^2u),Lu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k \right|= \\
&\left|<L(w^2u),Lu>_k-<wL(wu),Lu>_k+<wL(wu),Lu>_k\\
&-<L(wu),wLu>_k+<L(wu),wLu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k\right|\\
&\leq \left|<(Lw-wL)(wu),Lu>_k\right|+\left|<wL(wu),Lu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k\right|\\
&+\left|<L(wu),(wL-Lw)u>_k\right|
\end{align*}
```

Comment: A comment not related to pairing `\left` and `\right` directives, but about how to write the "angle" symbols around inner products. You shouldn't use `<` and `>`, in part because the spacing will be quite wrong. It's much better to use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\left` can not live without `\right` at the same line. You may skip it by adding `\right.` or `\left.` which "closes" the line.

```
\begin{align*}
&\left|<L(w^2u),Lu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k \right|= \\
&\left|<L(w^2u),Lu>_k-<wL(wu),Lu>_k+<wL(wu),Lu>_k\right.\\
&\left.-<L(wu),wLu>_k+<L(wu),wLu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k\right|\\
&\leq \left|<(Lw-wL)(wu),Lu>_k\right|+\left|<wL(wu),Lu>_k-<L(wu),L(wu)>_k\right|\\
&+\left|<L(wu),(wL-Lw)u>_k\right|
\end{align*}
```