# split doesn't want to split \left and \right

Tags: math-mode

In short,

I have :

`\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a = & \left | \dfrac{b}{c} \\
    & + \dfrac{d}{e} \right |
\end{split}
\end{equation}`

and it complains that I want to split `\left` and `\right`, if I remove those everything is ok.

Please suggest what to do in this case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! This question seems already answered in [How to make left right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/) If that helps, please let us know.

Comment: Yes. that helped too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `\left`needs `\right`, even empty:

```
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split} a = & \left | \dfrac{b}{c} \right.\\
 & \left.{}+ \dfrac{d}{e} \right | \end{split} 
\end{equation}
```

However, it is better to use pairs of the type `\bigl` and `\bigr`, `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`, `\biggl` and `\biggr`, and so on. LaTeX can choose pairs of an improper height if, e.g., a box in the first line has different height than this one in the second line.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. And, yes, great point with different size heights on different lines.