# Exam Class : Multicolumn : Symbol (displaystyle) into two lines

Tags: symbols, equations, exam, displaystyle

How can we break formula mentioned below into into two lines?

```
$\displaystyle \boldsymbol{{\left( {x\log x} \right)^{\log \log x}}\left\{ {\frac{1}
{{x\log x}}\left( {\log x + \log \log x} \right) + \left( {\log \log x} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{{x\log x}}} \right)} \right\} }$
```

FYI: I'm using two column layout and this symbol is getting overlapped over next column.

EDIT: Added sample tex file having issue mentioned above:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in,headheight=3.5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}   \begin{multicols}{2} \begin{questions}
\question[4] Ref: (111)\\If\ $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{y = {\left( {x\log x} \right)^{\log \log x}} }$ , then\ $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{\frac{{dy}}
{{dx}} =  }$
\begin{choices} \choice $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{{\left( {x\log x} \right)^{\log \log x}}\left\{ {\frac{1}
{{x\log x}}\left( {\log x + \log \log x} \right) + \left( {\log \log x} \right)\left( {\frac{1}
{x} + \frac{1}
{{x\log x}}} \right)} \right\} }$
\choice $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{{\left( {x\log x} \right)^{x\log x}}\log \log x\left[ {\frac{2}
{{\log x}} + \frac{1}
{x}} \right] }$
\choice $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{{\left( {x\log x} \right)^{x\log x}}\frac{{\log \log x}}
{x}\left[ {\frac{1}
{{\log x}} + 1} \right] }$
\choice none of these
 \end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines?rq=1

Comment: Thank Papiro, I tried that, it's giving Latex Error : "\item invalid in math mode" . I'm using exam class with two column layout. Symbol mentioned above is one of the \choice in Multiple choice question.

Comment: My misunderstanding, then.  Could you post an MWE?

Comment: I've added sample tex file

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was caused by having a `\left` `\right` pair break across a line.  For reasons unknown to me, this can't be done.  Use `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, or `\Bigg` as appropriate when you need this.

Adding the [`breqn`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines) package allows this functionality.

Note that you cannot use `\boldsymbol` with a line break or an alginment marker (`&`), either.
I recommend against using bold math this way *anyway*, but as a workaround, you can just embolden each line separately.

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in,headheight=3.5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{nonfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\dydx}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{questions}
    \question[4] Ref: (111)

    If $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{y = {\left( {x\log x} \right)^{\log \log x}}}$ , then $\displaystyle \boldsymbol{\dydx =}$
    \begin{choices}
      \choice \parbox{\linewidth}{
        \def\mypr#1{\left(#1\right)} % clarity
        \def\mybr#1{\left\{#1\right\}} % clarity
      \begin{align*}
        \boldsymbol{\mypr{x\log x}^{\log \log x}} &\boldsymbol{\Big\{\frac{1}{x\log x} \mypr{\log x + \log \log x}} \\
              &\boldsymbol{+ \mypr{\log \log x} \mypr{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x\log x}} \Big\}}
      \end{align*}
      }
      \choice\parbox{\linewidth}{
      \begin{equation*}
        \boldsymbol{{\left( {x\log x} \right)^{x\log x}}\log \log x\left[ {\frac{2}
            {{\log x}} + \frac{1}
            {x}} \right] }
      \end{equation*}
      }
      \choice \parbox{\linewidth}{
      \begin{equation*}
        \boldsymbol{{\left( {x\log x} \right)^{x\log x}}\frac{{\log \log x}}
        {x}\left[ {\frac{1}
            {{\log x}} + 1} \right] }
      \end{equation*}
      }
      \choice none of these
    \end{choices}
    \question \lipsum
  \end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the requirement that `\left` and `\right` be matched within a "cell" of an alignment (the component between an end of a line and a `&` or between two `&`s is built into tex itself; explained in *the texbook*, p.148: "TeX needs to typeset the subformula that appears between `\left` and \`right` before it can decide how big to make the delimiters."