# Write a multi-line equation with unmatched \left( and \right)

Tags: align

how can i write this long equation in beamer

```
 \mathbb{E}^{x}[f(X_{\tau})]&=f(x)+\mathbb{E}^{x}\left[\int_{0}^{\tau}\left(\sum_{i}u_{i}  (s,\omega)\frac{\partial
f}{\partial
x_{i}}(X_{s})+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(v.v^{T})_{i,j}(s,\omega)\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial
x_{i}\partial x_{j}}(X_{s}) \right)\diff s \right]
```

guz when i use  align give error told me that  Missing of { that's because \right) or \right]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
     \usepackage{amsmath}
      \usepackage{amssymb}
       \newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\mathopen{}\mathrm{d}}
     \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}^{x}[f(X_{\tau})]&=f(x)+\mathbb{E}^{x}\left[\int_{0}^{\tau}\left(\sum_{i}u_{i}(s,\omega)\frac{\partial
    f}{\partial x_{i}}(X_{s})\\
    &+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(v.v^{T})_{i,j}(s,\omega)\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial
    x_{i}\partial x_{j}}(X_{s}) \right)\diff s \right] \end{align*}
     \end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE whenever possible- it helps folks that look at your question :)

Comment: this question, and others, provide useful information: [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/579).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to match an unpaired `\left<( [ {>` and `\right<) ] }>` is to use `\right.` or `\left.`

Here's a complete MWE that demonstrates the idea

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\mathopen{}\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{align*}
        \mathbb{E}^{x}[f(X_{\tau})] & =f(x)+\mathbb{E}^{x}\left[\int_{0}^{\tau}\left(\sum_{i}u_{i}(s,\omega)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}(X_{s})\right.\right.                \\
                                    & \left.\left.+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}(v.v^{T})_{i,j}(s,\omega)\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}(X_{s}) \right)\diff s \right] 
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Some folks would recommend that you use `\bigg` instead, or perhaps add a `vphantom` so that the measuring is exact.

Comment: @Educ glad it helped :) your edit is fine, but would have been unnecessary if you had provided a complete MWE- something to remember for the future :)

Comment: Given that the big round paren and square bracket on the second line appear to be *much larger* than they are on the first line, use of explicit `\bigg` (or even `\Bigg`) directives would seem to be indicated.

Comment: @Mico yes, indeed- or perhaps the `vphantom` idea I mentioned

Comment: The downside of the `\vphantom` method is that it tends to clutter up the code. I think it's much easier to simply eyeball the situation and decide that `\bigg` is the size to go on both lines...