# How do I type a single bracket?

Tags: brackets

How do you produce a single bracket in LaTeX? I just want to insert a " [ " without closing the bracket. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for. What is wrong with simply typing the `[` character? And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Exactly, just press the `[` key on your keyboard. But if you want an expansible bracket to be used within a math expression use `\left[ ... \right.` (the period is part of the command).

Comment: While your editor may protest in terms of an unmatched bracket, it's perfectly fine to just use `[` as-is. If you're using it in an extensible sense (like `\left[`), then you need a corresponding empty `\right.`.

Comment: That was the problem, the editor did not seem to like { [ } but yes, it does work.

Comment: Possibly interesting as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/412

Answer (score 26):

If you wish to have have a scaleable bracket you should use the following:

```
\[ % Enter math mode
  \left[ your_formula_goes_here\right]
\]
```

If you want to keep it only on one side, use:

```
\[ % Enter math mode
  \left[ your_formula_goes_here\right.
\]
```

or

```
\[ % Enter math mode
  \left. your_formula_goes_here\right]
\]
```

depending on the side.

The important part is to always close with `\right<**>` whatever you opened with `\left<*>`. Note, as @Werner mentioned, that `*` and `**` could be different as in `\(\left] x^{x^{x^x}}\right\}\)`.

Comment: Note that `\right[` is perfectly acceptable as well, as in `\left]...\right[`, perhaps. :)