# How do I write a right bracket without writing a left one?

Tags: brackets, braces

I need to use `\right]` in one of my lines, but if I don't write `\left[` in the same formula I get an error (Using texmaker).

What I want to do is to type the range of a function, as in $F(x)]_{0}^{5}$. The problem is I can't use a regular bracket `]` because of the line height (There are several fractions in there).

Is there any alternative to `\right]` that allows me to skip the left one?

I've seen several questions regarding curly braces (Problem being you need to write `\left\{`, but none that answers this particular question.

Comment: you'll need `\left.` there must be a duplicate somewhere?...

Comment: `\left.` <expression> `\right]`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34902/what-does-right-do

Comment: @cmhughes There must probably be, but I haven't been able to locate it. Jubobs' link would be if it were easier to find while searching.

Comment: [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290) or [How do I type a single bracket?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151941)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use this

```
\[f(x) = \left.mx + b \right]\]

\[f(x) = \left.mx + b \right\}\]
```

for left bracket,

```
\[f(x) = \left[mx + b \right.\]

\[f(x) = \left\{mx + b \right.\]
```

Comment: Wow exactly! I didn't know about that, thank you.