# Error while equation splitting with align environment

Tags: align

I am splitting an equation using the following command:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
    \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    \delta \dot A &=-\left [ -\delta b_z-\omega^e\cos \varphi\delta\varphi-\frac{v_e\sec^2\varphi\delta\varphi}{R_N+h}-\frac{\tan\varphi\delta v_e}{R_N+h} \nonumber\\
    &+\frac{v_e\tan\varphi\delta h}{(R_N+h)^2} \right ]
    \end{align}
    \end{document}
```

However it gives me an error that I have extra } etc. I am using similar thing elsewhere with no problem at all. 
Can somebody please tell me what is going on and how can i fix it.
Thanks

Comment: would you mind adding your preamble/making this a full MWE?

Comment: related: [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't split `\left` and `\right` across lines. You need to size the brackets yourself using `\big`, `\Big`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\delta \dot A &=-\bigg[ -\delta b_z-\omega^e\cos \varphi\delta\varphi    
                        -\frac{v_e\sec^2\varphi\delta\varphi}{R_N+h}
                        -\frac{\tan\varphi\delta v_e}{R_N+h}\nonumber\\  
& +\frac{v_e\tan\varphi\delta h}{(R_N+h)^2} \bigg] 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to insert `\qquad` after the `&` symbol in the second row of the equation.

Comment: Or use `{} & =` on the first row

Comment: @daleif -- huh?  with ordinary `align`, that doesn't make any difference at all.  are you thinking of something from `mathtools`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton sorry, should have been `= {} & `