# Problem about the sizes of the brackets after linebreaks

Tags: line-breaking, brackets

I have a problem in the brackets of the following code:

```
\begin{align}
  S = \int d^Dx \left\{ \mathscr{L}_{m=0} - \frac{1}{2}m^2(h_{\mu \nu}h^{\mu \nu} - h^2)
    - \frac{1}{2}m^2F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} - 2m^2\left(h_{\mu \nu}\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} 
    - h \partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}\right) \right. \nonumber \\ 
    + \left. \kappa h_{\mu \nu}T^{\mu \nu} - 2\kappa A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}T^{\mu \nu} \right\}
\end{align}
```

which has the output

[image: output of the code]

As you see, the bracket in the second line has a different size than the corresponding bracket in the first line. I tried to use `\Big\}` and also `Bigg\}` but although they give same sized brackets in both lines, this time the size differs from the original size I obtained when I use `\right\}` command. `\Big\}` gives a smaller size while `Bigg\}` gives a bigger one. For the proper look of my document I should have the sizes of the brackets same everywhere. So I need a way to change the bracket size of the second line while keeping the bracket in the first line as it is. Can anybody help?

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to make \left, \right pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a fixed size is the correct approach here, perhaps you want `\bigg` which is between `\Big` and `\Bigg` but you should use `\biggl\{` and `\biggr\}` to get the correct open and close spacing.