# Carrying modulus sign for two lines

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Is it possible to carry the **modulus sign** $| . |$ in two lines. I just put a mwe for a hypothetical example. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (2x+1)^{n} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^n \right) \right|&=\left| -(2x+1) \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x \right) + (2x+1)^2 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^2 \right) - (2x+1)^3 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^3 \right) + (2x+1)^4 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^4 \right) \\
&\dots +(-1)^{n-1} (2x+1)^{n-1} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^{n-1} \right) +(-1)^n (2x+1)^n \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^n \right)  \right|  
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should avoid using `\left|`...`\right|` across a break in an equation. Using `\bigl|`...`\bigr|` or `\biggl|`...`\biggr|` (as suggested in [How to make `\left`, `\right` pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/5764)) works. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWTsf.png).

Comment: Just consider the bars like other fences.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly clear what you intend, but you can use `|...|` around any inline alignment such as `aligned` (but not `split` which has to control the full width of the expression)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (2x+1)^{n} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^n \right)
=
\left|
\begin{aligned}
&
 -(2x+1) \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x \right) + (2x+1)^2 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^2 \right) - 
(2x+1)^3 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^3 \right) + (2x+1)^4 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^4 \right) \\
&\dots
 +(-1)^{n-1} (2x+1)^{n-1} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^{n-1} \right) +(-1)^n (2x+1)^n \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} x^n \right)
\end{aligned}
 \right|  
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But that's not what I needed. I need the \left|  to start after the equal sign and second line to be ended with a \right|.

Comment: well just remove the left and right and use |  or `\bigl|` and `\bigr|` (and if that's what you meant, it will be a duplicate question, I will find a link) @Fib1123