# How do I prevent large horizontal gaps when aligning?

Tags: align, split

The closest solution to what I'm looking for that I've been able to come up with so far is this

```
\[
\begin{align*}
A & = & B & C\\
& = & B & (D\\
& & + & E)
\end{align*}
\]
```

which produces this

[image: output of the previous code]

Now that's fairly close to what I'm intending. D and E are fairly large expressions, so I have to put them on separate lines and having them aligned like this is aesthetically quite pleasing. But there's this mysterious gap between the equal signs and the B's. Is there a way to get rid of that? Or perhaps a wholly different approach to typesetting this?

Comment: Omit the `&` after the `=`.

Comment: Then I end up with a large gap between B and C as well as B and (D.

Comment: What you should understand is that is that three `&` means *two* columns of alignment, and these columns are separated by some  length which is automatically inserted (this is the difference with `alignat`).

Comment: Maybe showing a real example can clarify the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m not sure I’ve understood what you want to do, but I’d go for something like this:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

An example:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        A &= \text{1st fairly large expr.}\cdot C \\
            &=\text{1st fairly large expr.} \cdot
            \begin{aligned}[t]
                & (\text{2nd fairly large expr.} \\
                & \quad + \text{3rd fairly large expr.})
            \end{aligned}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
This assumes that you want to label the whole block with a single
equation number.

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of the code sample]

---

### Another option

If you want each line to be numbered, use `alignat`:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\myexpr}[1]{%
    \langle\text{#1 fairly large expr.}\rangle
}



\begin{document}

An example:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        A &= \myexpr{1st} \cdot C \\
            &= \myexpr{1st} \cdot
            \begin{aligned}[t]
                & (\myexpr{2nd} \\
                & \quad + \myexpr{3rd})
            \end{aligned}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
This assumes you want to label the whole block with a single equation number.
Individual lines can be numbered with the help of the \texttt{alignat}
environment:

\begin{alignat}{2}
    A &= \myexpr{1st} && \cdot C \\
        &= \myexpr{1st}
            && \cdot (\myexpr{2nd} \notag \\ % no number on this line
        &   && \mathbin{\hphantom{\cdot}} \quad {} + \myexpr{3rd})
\end{alignat}
We've also shown how to suppress the equation number on a particular line.

\end{document}
```

Note how the nature of binary operator of the phantom `\cdot` is preserved, so that it is properly spaced.

The output is:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

Comment: I tried fiddling with nested `split` but couldn't get that to work the way I wanted. What makes `aligned` the right choice here?

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff: The sheer fact that you want nested alignments… :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Option 1:
\begin{align*}
  A = {} & B C \\
    = {} & B (D \\
         & \phantom{B} + E)
\end{align*}

Option 2:
\begin{align*}
  A &= B C \\
    &= B (D \\
    &\phantom{{}= B} + E)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Since you're splitting the parentheses across multiple lines, you can't use `\left`-`\right`. For more on this, see [How to make `\left`, `\right` pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/5764)