# Array inside an equation: open bracket in a line and close in another line

Tags: math-mode, equations, arrays, brackets

This code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
\begin{array}{l}
\left[ \displaystyle \frac{e^{ix}}{2} = \\
= \sin (x) + \cos (x) \right]
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

generates an error:

```
Missing \right. inserted. \left[ \displaystyle \frac{e^{ix}}{2} = \\
Extra \right. = \sin (x) + \cos (x) \right]
```

If I modify it as

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
\begin{array}{l}
\left[ \displaystyle \frac{e^{ix}}{2} = \right. \\
= \left. \sin (x) + \cos (x) \right]
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

it can be built, but the closing square bracket `\right]` appears smaller than the opening `\left[`. I would like to have them instead of the same dimensions (as `\left[`).

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Set the size manually using `\biggl[` and `\biggr]`.

Comment: Other answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/2417)

Comment: also don't use `array` for displayed equations use an amsmath alignment such as `align` or ``aligned` they use display style