# Bracket when breaking line in align

Tags: align, line-breaking

I have read several line-breaking inside `align` environment but I fail to deal with the bracket `{}`. LaTex seems not recognize `\left\{` and `\right\}` belong to the same equation when I break the line.

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
    s_{percent-log} (y,y') &= \frac{1}{3} \left\{ \frac{\min[\log(0+1),\log(1+1)]}{\max[\log(0+1),\log(1+1)]} \\
    & \qquad + \frac{\min[\log(5+1),\log(4+1)]}{\max[\log(5+1),\log(4+1)]} \\
    & \qquad + \frac{\min[\log(2+1),\log(2+1)]}{\max[\log(2+1),\log(2+1)]} \right\} \\
    &\approx 0.46387 \\
    d_{percent-log} (y,y') &\approx 0.53613 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: There is no question here. Do you mean to ask about spanning left-right over a line break? If so it may be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines

Comment: Hey David. So I looked for wrong key words here :). Thank you very much :)