# Equation split with bracelet over one line

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, brackets, split

I have a problem getting my equation typed the right way.

Following Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
% Matrizen
\newcommand{\A}{\underline{\mathrm{A}}}
\newcommand{\B}{\underline{\mathrm{B}}}
\newcommand{\CM}{\underline{\mathrm{C}}}
\newcommand{\D}{\underline{\mathrm{D}}}
% Zustandsvektor
\newcommand{\zv}{\dot{\vec{\mathrm{x}}}}
\newcommand{\xv}{\vec{\mathrm{x}}}
% Zustandsgrößen
\newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}
% Eingangsgrößen
\newcommand{\Uin}{\mathrm{U_{in}}}
\newcommand{\UD}[1]{\mathrm{U_{D_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Usboost}{\mathrm{U_{S_{boost}}}}
\newcommand{\UAC}{\mathrm{U_{AC}}}
% Bauteile
\newcommand{\C}[1]{\mathrm{C_{#1}}}
\newcommand{\rC}[1]{\mathrm{r_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\rsbuck}{\mathrm{r_{S_{buck}}}}
%\newcommand{\L}{\mathrm{L}}
\newcommand{\rL}{\mathrm{r_L}}
\newcommand{\rD}[1]{\mathrm{r_{D_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\rAC}{\mathrm{r_{AC}}}
\newcommand{\ddt}[1]{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}t}}
% Spannungen
\newcommand{\urC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{r_{C_{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\urL}{\mathrm{u_{r_L}}}
\newcommand{\urAC}{\mathrm{u_{r_{AC}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\paragraph*{Zustandsgröße $\iL$:}\mbox{}\\
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
    \ddt{\langle\iL\rangle}\left(\delta\mathrm{T}\right)+\ddt{\langle\iL\rangle}\left(1-\delta\right)\mathrm{T} =\\ 
    \left(\delta\mathrm{T}\right) \left(\left(\dfrac{-\rsbuck\rC{2}-\rsbuck\rAC-\rD{1}\rC{2}-\rD{1}\rAC-\rAC\rC{2}-\rL\rAC-\rL\rC{2}}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)} \right)\iL 
    +\left(\dfrac{-\rAC}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)}\right)\uC{2} %\\
    + \left(\dfrac{-\rC{2}}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)}\right)\UAC + \dfrac{\Uin-\UD{1}}{\mathrm{L}} \right)\\
    + \left(1-\delta\right)\mathrm{T}\left( \left(\dfrac{-\rD{2}\rC{2}-\rD{2}\rAC-\rD{1}\rC{2}-\rD{1}\rAC-\rAC\rC{2}-\rL\rAC-\rL\rC{2}}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2+\rAC}\right)}\right)\iL
    + \left(\dfrac{-\rAC}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)}\right)\uC{2}
    + \left(\dfrac{-\rC{2}}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)}\right)\UAC + \dfrac{-\UD{2}-\UD{1}}{\mathrm{L}} \right)
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image: Output]

is there a way to type it like this?

```
   dil/dt = \left( (a)iL + (b)*uc2
          + (c)*UAC + d \right) (deltaT)
          + \left( (e)iL + (f)*uc2
          + (g)*UAC + h \right) (1-delta)T
```

The problem I discovered is, thats not possible to use \left(\right) in an split-enviroment. The next problem is that i want to align the (+) of the terms to the equal-Symbol(=), but i read, its not allowed using & in an \left(\right) enviroment.

Would be nice if someone can help me with this.

Comment: You should use manual sizes for the brackets: `\big`, `\bigg`,... See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/82917

Comment: I will take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add my proposal which certainly won't be the best, but the split effect is given by the environment `aligned`. I also tried to better arrange the brackets to have a more homogeneous appearance. Here there is a screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
        \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
        \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
        \usepackage{siunitx}
        \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
        % Matrizen
        \newcommand{\A}{\underline{\mathrm{A}}}
        \newcommand{\B}{\underline{\mathrm{B}}}
        \newcommand{\CM}{\underline{\mathrm{C}}}
        \newcommand{\D}{\underline{\mathrm{D}}}
        % Zustandsvektor
        \newcommand{\zv}{\dot{\vec{\mathrm{x}}}}
        \newcommand{\xv}{\vec{\mathrm{x}}}
        % Zustandsgrößen
        \newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
        \newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}
        % Eingangsgrößen
        \newcommand{\Uin}{\mathrm{U_{in}}}
        \newcommand{\UD}[1]{\mathrm{U_{D_{#1}}}}
        \newcommand{\Usboost}{\mathrm{U_{S_{boost}}}}
        \newcommand{\UAC}{\mathrm{U_{AC}}}
        % Bauteile
        \newcommand{\C}[1]{\mathrm{C_{#1}}}
        \newcommand{\rC}[1]{\mathrm{r_{C_{#1}}}}
        \newcommand{\rsbuck}{\mathrm{r_{S_{buck}}}}
        %\newcommand{\L}{\mathrm{L}}
        \newcommand{\rL}{\mathrm{r_L}}
        \newcommand{\rD}[1]{\mathrm{r_{D_{#1}}}}
        \newcommand{\rAC}{\mathrm{r_{AC}}}
        \newcommand{\ddt}[1]{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}t}}
        % Spannungen
        \newcommand{\urC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{r_{C_{#1}}}}}
        \newcommand{\urL}{\mathrm{u_{r_L}}}
        \newcommand{\urAC}{\mathrm{u_{r_{AC}}}}

        \begin{document}
        \begin{landscape}
        \paragraph*{Zustandsgröße $\iL$:}\mbox{}\\
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
           \ddt{\langle\iL\rangle}(\delta\mathrm{T})+\ddt{\langle\iL\rangle}(1-\delta)\mathrm{T} &= \\ 
        &=\left(\delta\mathrm{T}\right) \Bigg(\Bigg(\dfrac{-\rsbuck\rC{2}-\rsbuck\rAC-\rD{1}\rC{2}-\rD{1}\rAC-\rAC\rC{2}-\rL\rAC-\rL\rC{2}}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)} \Bigg)\iL \\
            &+\left(\dfrac{-\rAC}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)}\right)\uC{2} + \left(\dfrac{-\rC{2}}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)}\right)\UAC + \dfrac{\Uin-\UD{1}}{\mathrm{L}}\Bigg)\\
            &+ \left(1-\delta\right)\mathrm{T}\Bigg(\left(\dfrac{-\rD{2}\rC{2}-\rD{2}\rAC-\rD{1}\rC{2}-\rD{1}\rAC-\rAC\rC{2}-\rL\rAC-\rL\rC{2}}{\mathrm{L} (\rC{2+\rAC})}\right)\iL\\
            &+ \left(\dfrac{-\rAC}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)}\right)\uC{2} 
            + \left(\dfrac{-\rC{2}}{\mathrm{L}\left(\rC{2}+\rAC\right)}\right)\UAC + \dfrac{-\UD{2}-\UD{1}}{\mathrm{L}} \Bigg) 
           \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
        \end{landscape}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: @adaptive I hope you like it. You are free to choose other answers if they will exist. I was happy to help you. My greetings.