# Automatic brackets size with \left(...\right) fails for \text{...} exponents

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I noticed that the automatic adjustment size for parentheses by use of `\left(...\right)` "fails" in two cases I use a lot:

**Case one**:

When a upper index is set as `\text{...}`. I typeset label-indices as `\text{...}` (for example `$y^\text{p}$` for predicted y-values) since this is how they are usually formatted in the physics context to distinguish labels from mathematical indices.

I marked the upper and lower ends of the parentheses for just brackets (green), `\left(...\right)` (red) and `\left(...^\text{...}\right)` (blue). Note that the bracket size for the latter is adjusted, but not to the right size.
[image]

**Case two:**

When having large equations in parentheses spanning multiple lines, I break the lines with

```
\begin{align}
    \left[ ... \right. \\
    \left. ... \right]
\end{align}
```

In this case, the size of the square brackets is not adjusted synchronously. I understand that this is because the size is determined within a line instead of within the `\left[...\right]` pair.

**Question:**

The question connecting this two cases is: Is it possible to access the logic of how the sizes are determined? (Another use case is to increase nested brackets automatically).

Example:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=TeX,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
}
\begin{document}

Case one:
\begin{align*}
    (y_i^f) + \left(y_i^f\right) + \left(y_i^\text{f}\right)
\end{align*}


Case two:
\begin{align*}
    y=& \left[ \frac{x}{c} \right. \\
    &+\left. f(x)\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not directly related but using `\text{f}` is wrong markup (and slow) it will pick up whatever font is current outside the math, better to use `^{\mathrm{f}}`

Comment: Anyway, it's better, typographically, to adjust the delimiters size by hand, with `\bigl... \bigr`, `\Bigr ... \Bigr` and the like.

Comment: It is better not to ask two unrelated questions in the same post, the align question is a FAQ, and duplicate)  (use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`, I'll find a link to the standard answer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21290/how-to-make-left-right-pairs-of-delimiter-work-over-multiple-lines

Comment: The code for the first question is part of the example, I know I can adjust size by hand, but am interested in adjusting \left(...\right) to work correctly. Thank you for the comment with ^{\mathrm{f}} (although it produces the same result here)

Comment: It _is_ working correctly,

Comment: @audiophiel to see the difference with `\text` try placing this in a theorem using italic text for example.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(y^f_i\right) \left(y^{\text{f}}_i\right) \left(y^{\mathrm{f}}_i\right) 
\]
\end{document}
```

The italic f is raised higher to keep it away from the subscript so simply forces TeX to choose an overlarge delimiter size. This demonstrates why it is usually better to choose the size manually with a simple `(` or an explicit `\bigl(...\bigr)` pair if a larger size is needed.

So the automatically chosen size is Ok for `\mathrm` (which should be used in preference to `\text`) although personally I would just use the default size here and not use `\left\right` at all:

[image]

```
\[
(y^{\mathrm{f}}_i)\left(y^{\mathrm{f}}_i\right) 
\]
```

Comment: note that this is not really about `\text` or `mathrm`   it is about _italic f_ If you changed your example to use a superscript `n` you would see no difference. It is simply that the italic f has a descender and the roman one does not

Comment: So the uppermost bow of the f should exceed the hight of the bracket? I expected the point was that the brackets "wrap" their content (what is the case for \left( y^f \right) )

Comment: At the risk of sounding like egreg there is no requirement that the brackets are taller than their content (in fact they are traditionally a little bit less, tex has parameters `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` to control how much smaller than the content is acceptable)