# Line breaking equation beginning and ending with large brace

Tags: latex3

I have a very long equation that begins and ends with a curly brace.  I would like it to extend over multiple lines.  I tried the following

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{eqnarray}  \label{eq:cohensDCSs3}
    \hat{\mathcal{A}}_c^{\pm}= \left \{\bf{s}: \\ \nonumber
    \pm \frac{k}{\sqrt{N}}\right\}
\end{eqnarray}


\end{document}
```

and get the following error message

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \right.
<template> }
            $\@eqnsel \endtemplate 
l.9 ...l{A}}_c^{\pm}= \left \{\bf{s}: \\ \nonumber
                                              
?
```

I do not get this error message if I leave out the "\\ \nonumber" part.

Edit.
Thank you for the replies.  But I wanted a large brace at the beginning of the first line and a large brace at the end of the last line.  The following is what I want.
[image]

The following code does what I want.  The braces expand with the equation which begins and ends with a brace.  I don't want any braces to span all of the lines.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{eqnarray}
    \hat{\mathcal{A}}_c^{\pm}=  \left\{\bf{s}: \right. \\     \nonumber
    \left. \pm \frac{k}{\sqrt{N}}\right\}
    \end{eqnarray}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Source of your problems solved here: [How to make `\left`, `\right` pairs of delimiter work over multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21290/5764)

Comment: What you want is not at all clear.  The snippet you've given has a much smaller `{` placed to the right of where the second line starts, so I don't think that's what you really want.  Bernard has a nice answer.  Is that what you want?  If not, why not?  You can also use sizing commands like `\biggl` and `\biggr` to adjust the `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: @Werner.  Yes it does.  I had not seen that question.

Answer (score 3):

Does it work for you or I misunderstand You?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{eqnarray}  \label{eq:cohensDCSs3}
    \hat{\mathcal{A}}_c^{\pm}=  \lbrace\bf{s}: \\ \nonumber
    \pm \frac{k}{\sqrt{N}}\rbrace
\end{eqnarray}


\end{document}
```

Just replace  **\left{** to the *"**\lbrace**"* and same *"**\rbrace**"*

Comment: This is equivalent to deleting `\left` and `\right`.  Presumably OP has them for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use eqnarray – the spacing at the alignment point is not good.  I propose this simple solution with left-aligned Bmatrix:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:cohensDCSs3}
      \hat{\mathcal{A}}_c^{\pm}= \begin{Bmatrix*}[l]\bf{s}: \\
    \pm \frac{k}{\sqrt{N}}\end{Bmatrix*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]