# How to insert equal height brackets on both sides while wrapping a new line？

Tags: amsmath, brackets, physics, braket

I'd like to input a long equation, so I had to cut it into two lines. But, there's a couple of {} at the start of the first line of the equation and the end of the second line of the equation, and the 'equal height brackets' doesn't support `\\` in it. I've used the `\qty{}` command of the package `physics`, or the `\ab\{\}` command of the package `physics2`, just like the code below:

```tex
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{fixdif,physics2}
\def\e{\mathrm{e}}
\usephysicsmodule{ab,ab.legacy,braket,nabla.legacy}
\def\Re{\mathrm{Re}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        J_L(t)&=\frac{2e}{\hbar}\Re\ab\{\sum_{k,\alpha\in L}{V_{k\alpha,n(t)}G_{n,k\alpha}^<(t,t)}\}\\
        &\xlongequal{\sum_{n}\sum_m=\sum_{n,m}}\frac{2e}{\hbar}\Re\ab\{\sum_{\substack{k,\alpha\in L\\n,m}}V_{k\alpha,n}(t)\int_{-\infty}^t\d t_1V_{k\alpha,m}^*\ab(t_1)\times\ab[G_{nm}^r\ab(t,t_1)\times\ab(\i f\ab(\epsilon_{k\alpha}^0)\exp\ab[-\i\int_{t}^{t_1}{\d t_2\epsilon_{k\alpha}(t_2)}])\\
        &\ \ +G_{nm}^<\ab(t,t_1)\times\ab(\i\theta\ab(-t_1+t)\exp\ab[-\i\int_{t}^{t_1}{\d t_2\epsilon_{k\alpha}(t_2)}])\vphantom{\int_t^{t_1}}]\}\\
      \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

they all returned me errors:

```shell
Extra }, or forgotten \right.
<template> }
Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
```

Then, I used the command `\left\{` at the at the start of the first line of the equation and `\right\}` at the end of the second line of the equation, however it also returned me the errors above.

Then, I used the command `\left\{` at the start of the first line and `\right.` at the end of the first line, used the command `\left.` at the start of the second line and `\right\}` at the end of the second line, the errors disappeared, however, the height of the right bracket `}` doesn't equal to the height of the left bracket `{`.
[image]

The code is just like below:

```tex
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{fixdif,physics2}
\def\e{\mathrm{e}}
\usephysicsmodule{ab,ab.legacy,braket,nabla.legacy}
\def\Re{\mathrm{Re}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        J_L(t)&=\frac{2e}{\hbar}\Re\ab\{\sum_{k,\alpha\in L}{V_{k\alpha,n(t)}G_{n,k\alpha}^<(t,t)}\}\\
        &\xlongequal{\sum_{n}\sum_m=\sum_{n,m}}\frac{2e}{\hbar}\Re\left\{\sum_{\substack{k,\alpha\in L\\n,m}}V_{k\alpha,n}(t)\int_{-\infty}^t\d t_1V_{k\alpha,m}^*\ab(t_1)\times\left[G_{nm}^r\ab(t,t_1)\times\ab(\i f\ab(\epsilon_{k\alpha}^0)\exp\ab[-\i\int_{t}^{t_1}{\d t_2\epsilon_{k\alpha}(t_2)}])\right.\right.\\
        &\ \ \left.\left.+G_{nm}^<\ab(t,t_1)\times\ab(\i\theta\ab(-t_1+t)\exp\ab[-\i\int_{t}^{t_1}{\d t_2\epsilon_{k\alpha}(t_2)}])\vphantom{\int_t^{t_1}}\right]\right\}\\
      \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Finally, I found that I can add a 'virtual' height of the first line, is just add the command `\vphantom{\sum_{\substack{k,\alpha\in L\\n,m}}}` before the `\right\}` at the end of the second line, just like the code below:

```tex
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{fixdif,physics2}
\def\e{\mathrm{e}}
\usephysicsmodule{ab,ab.legacy,braket,nabla.legacy}
\def\Re{\mathrm{Re}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        J_L(t)&=\frac{2e}{\hbar}\Re\ab\{\sum_{k,\alpha\in L}{V_{k\alpha,n(t)}G_{n,k\alpha}^<(t,t)}\}\\
        &\xlongequal{\sum_{n}\sum_m=\sum_{n,m}}\frac{2e}{\hbar}\Re\left\{\sum_{\substack{k,\alpha\in L\\n,m}}V_{k\alpha,n}(t)\int_{-\infty}^t\d t_1V_{k\alpha,m}^*\ab(t_1)\times\left[G_{nm}^r\ab(t,t_1)\times\ab(\i f\ab(\epsilon_{k\alpha}^0)\exp\ab[-\i\int_{t}^{t_1}{\d t_2\epsilon_{k\alpha}(t_2)}])\right.\right.\\
        &\ \ \left.\left.+G_{nm}^<\ab(t,t_1)\times\ab(\i\theta\ab(-t_1+t)\exp\ab[-\i\int_{t}^{t_1}{\d t_2\epsilon_{k\alpha}(t_2)}])\vphantom{\int_t^{t_1}}\right]\vphantom{\sum_{\substack{k,\alpha\in L\\n,m}}}\right\}\\
      \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The question is *'solved'*, this is the effect that I want:
[image]

However, this is too much trouble... I'd like to know if there's **a simple command** just like the command `\qty` of package `physics` or `\ab` of package `physics2` can achieve the effect I want?

Comment: I think you need to use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` or maybe `\biggl` and `\biggr` or whatever size fits you here.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21291/82917

Comment: Aside: The article document class doesn't recognize (and thus ignores) the option `9pt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than define and use various `\vphantom` contstructs, do learn how to use `\Bigg[lr]` and `\bigg[lr]`. Incidentally, your formula needs to be spread across four rows, not just three, in order for it not to protrude into the margins. Oh, and don't use `\def` unless you are willing to take the risk of clobbering pre-existing macros; the macro `\Re` is a case in point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[%9pt, % "9pt" is not a recognized option
               a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\smashoperator" macro
\usepackage{extarrows,fixdif}
\let\Re\relax % first, undefine the existing '\Re' macro
\DeclareMathOperator\Re{\mathrm{Re}} % next, redefine '\Re'
%\def\e{\mathrm{e}} % not needed 
\providecommand\I{\mathrm{i}} % imag. unit. Use only in math mode

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
J_L(t)
  &=\frac{2e}{\hbar} \Re\Biggl\{ \,
    \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{k,\alpha\in L}}
    V_{k\alpha,n(t)}G_{n,k\alpha}^<(t,t)\Biggr\}\\
  &\xlongequal{\sum_{n}\sum_m=\sum_{n,m}}
    \frac{2e}{\hbar} \Re\Biggl\{ \,
    \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\substack{k,\alpha\in L\\n,m}}}
    V_{k\alpha,n}(t)
    \int_{-\infty}^t \d t_1 V_{k\alpha,m}^* (t_1)\\
  &\quad
    \times\Biggl[G_{nm}^r(t,t_1)\times
    \biggl(\I f(\epsilon_{k\alpha}^0)
    \exp\biggl[-\I\int_{t}^{t_1} \d t_2\epsilon_{k\alpha}(t_2) 
    \biggr]\biggr) \\
  &\qquad
    +G_{nm}^< (t,t_1)\times\biggl(\I\theta(-t_1+t)
    \exp\biggl[-\I\int_{t}^{t_1} \d t_2\epsilon_{k\alpha}(t_2)
    \biggr]\biggr)
    \Biggr]\Biggr\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\i` throws warning in math mode. I'd suggest soething along the lines of `\newcommand*{\I}{\text{\i}}`, then one can redefine the imaginary unit (I think that's what it's supposed to be) as needed.

Comment: @campa - Good point. Let me fix this right away.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it `\textup` might be better. You don't want that to be italic in a theorem environment.

Comment: @campa - I ended up using `\mathrm{i}`. :-)

Comment: However, I feel that commands like big, bigg, Big or Bigg cannot control the height of the brackets as finely as the physics package

Comment: @Axia - What do you mean? First off, in your code, many of the `\ab` instructions have no effect at all; I wouldn't call that an example of "fine control". Second, the only time that `\bigg` and `\Bigg` fall short is if what's needed is tall delimiters bigger than `\Bigg`. However, that's not the case here.

Comment: I think the set of 'big' commands can’t set the height of the brackets finely, for example, the elements in the bracket is higher than the height of the bracket '\biggl{' but lower than the height of the bracket '\Biggl{', I want to control the height of bracket very accurate, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Axia - I have to disagree with the premise of your comment, which is that the sizes provided by `\big`, `\Big`, and `\bigg` and `\Bigg` are somehow not "fine enough". Naturally, you have every right to prefer to pursue an alternative approach, which by necessity will involve providing lots of `\left.` and `\right.` directives and coming up with lots of cleverly chosen `\vphantom` commands. If that's what you would rather do, I'm certainly not going to stop you. That said, I also have absolutely no desire to bicker with you on this subject.